# Issues with meteor-react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, meteor, html-templates

I have a started a new project using meteor-reactjs-mongodb combo. I am having a lot of issues since i am a beginner at those.

1)Initial compilation time is almost like 5 minutes. It would be my pleasure if you explain how to optimize.

2) I am using an html template for react front end. I have copied all the dependencies and plugins from the paid template. But it does not going that easy the way what i wanted. Should i look for a react template instead of html ?

All of your expertise about this matter are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First, you are asking more than one question in a single thread - Please delete this question and open one thread for each question. Second, please provide more background information on your questions. On the first things like: operating system, Meteor release, `package.json` and `./meteor/packages` content. On the second which template you bought (some link to the page) and if it is a Template that has been build with React and Meteor or only using React and another framework.

Comment: Please understand, that the success rate of getting answers on this site strongly depends on the quality of the question. If you need more information you can read in the help section on how to ask good questions.

Comment: I understood @Jankapunkt . Thank you for your response . I will follow  your instructions. I was in  a hurry . I changed from windows 10 to manjaro linux.  Now the performance improved and the compilation time decreased. Therefore i decided to build each component seperately in html structure on jsx pages.

Comment: Windows builds will speed up a lot with Meteor 1.8.1 but which has not ETA yet.